# Remove certain content types from search

Tags: 8, search

There are certain content types such as book pages that I don't want to appear on the search results page. 
I found example code implementing this on drupal 7 here

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_alter().
 * removes content types defined in the excluded_content_types array from search results
 */
function hook_query_alter(&$query) {
  $is_search = FALSE;
  $excluded_content_types = array(
      'product',
      'billboard',
    );
  foreach ($query->getTables() as $table) {
    if ($table['table'] == 'search_index') {
      $is_search = TRUE;
    }
  }
  if ($is_search) {
    foreach ($excluded_content_types as $content_type) {
      $query->condition('n.type', $content_type, '<>');
    }
  }
}
```

However I want to implement this in 8.
Is there a way to exclude certain content types from search results?

UPDATE: I've also attempted to restrict the search types from within the search-result.html.twig however it does not seem like I have the content type variable available.

```
{{ attach_library('classy/search-results') }}
{{ title_prefix }}

{{ dump(info_split) }}

<h3{{ title_attributes.addClass('search-result__title') }}>
  <a href="{{ url }}">{{ title }}</a>
</h3>
{{ title_suffix }}
<div class="search-result__snippet-info">
  {% if snippet %}
    <p{{ content_attributes.addClass('search-result__snippet') }}>{{ snippet }}</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% if info %}
    <p class="search-result__info">{{ info }}</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

When performing {{ dump(info_split) }} it does not show content type as an available variable.

Answer (score 3):

Configuring search is easy with Search API. Excluding node types from indexing is one of its basic config options.

https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api

When you set up your index and go to the configuration page, you can exclude bundles (types).

Comment: I'd rather intercept it and remove it in a hook or template instead. I'd like to avoid installing new modules, especially since I only plan on removing one content type, and there would be less than 10 nodes. Is that a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and i managed it by writing

```
YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables)
```

and by enabling advanced search for anonymous users. Also hide the options from users in

```
YOUR_THEME_NAME_form_search_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
```

use these functions and `kint($variables)` and `kint($form)`. Hope it will help

Comment: Where should I write these codes???

Comment: In your `YOUR_THEME_NAME.theme` file

Answer (score 0):

We created a new search plugin to restrict indexing of specific CTs.

```php
/**
 * Override standard core node search to exclude specific bundles from indexing.
 */
function mymodule_search_plugin_alter(array &$definitions): void {
  if (isset($definitions['node_search'])) {
    $definitions['node_search']['class'] = MyModuleNodeSearch::class;
  }
}
```

And just override **updateIndex** and **indexStatus** methods:

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Search;

use Drupal\node\Plugin\Search\NodeSearch;

/**
 * Extend core node search to exclude specific content types from search.
 */
class MyModuleNodeSearch extends NodeSearch {

  const EXCLUDED_BUNDLES = ['article', 'basic_page'];

  public function updateIndex() {
    // ...
    // parent stuff.
    $query->condition('n.type', self::EXCLUDED_BUNDLES, 'NOT IN');
    // ... other query stuff.
  }
  
  public function indexStatus() {
    $total = $this->database->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {node} [n] WHERE [n].[type] NOT IN ( :bundles[] )', [':bundles[]' => self::EXCLUDED_BUNDLES)->fetchField();
    $remaining = $this->database->query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [n].[nid]) FROM {node} [n] LEFT JOIN {search_dataset} [sd] ON [sd].[sid] = [n].[nid] AND [sd].[type] = :type WHERE ([sd].[sid] IS NULL OR [sd].[reindex] <> 0) AND [n].[type] NOT IN ( :bundles[] )", [
      ':type' => $this->getPluginId(),
      ':bundles[]' => self::EXCLUDED_BUNDLES,
    ])->fetchField();

    return ['remaining' => $remaining, 'total' => $total];
  }
}
```

Nowadays there are [lots of modules that allows you restrict indexing/showing specific CTs](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/111744#comment-13041339). Here is a module uses same approach as we: https://dgo.to/search_exclude

BTW: just in case if you need programmatically reindex core search via drush then use [this solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/313788/5501)